# custom keras loss function

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I want to write a custom loss function in keras, which also uses the gradient of the output w.r.t the input

```
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(200, input_dim=20, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(64, input_dim=20, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
          optimizer='rmsprop',
          metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Now, I want to replace the loss function. I only know how to write using tensorflow as follows:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 1], name="x") 
ext_f0 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 1], name="f") 
xx0 = tf.concat([[[R_variable['x_start'] * 1.0],[R_variable['x_end'] * 1.0]], x], 0)
yy0 = univAprox(xx0)
Boundary_y = yy0[0:2]
y = yy0[2:]
GradU = tf.gradients(y,x)  #***KEY***
GradSum = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(GradU)) / 2 * dx_train
FSum = tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(ext_f0,y)) * dx_train
loss = GradSum + FSum + Beta * tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(Boundary_y))
```

The key is I need to get the `GradU`. How should I do this in keras?

Answer (score 0):

You can write your custom loss function. All you should know is it's form:

```
def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
  # do something to compute loss
  ...
  return loss
```

And that should be it.

Comment: with y_true and y_pred, it seems that I can not do GradU. 'Cause I still need to have x?